# How to run this java recursive program that has complicated arguments?

Tags: java, recursion, program-entry-point

I am writing a program allowing the user to enter a 3 digit phone number and when they enter it, the program will return every combination of 3 letters put together (based on the letters each digit contains). Most phone digits have letters in it. For example, if the user types 6, 2, and 3, it should return the following:

```
MAD MBD MCD NAD NBD NCD OAD OBD OCD
MAE MBE MCE NAE NBE NCE OAE OBE OCE
MAF MBF MCF NAF NBF NCF OAF OBF OCF
```

I copied and pasted a code from the internet (There's no user input code) and now I addded a main method to run the program. I don't need help with getting user input code, but **which** method and **how** do I call the method to run the program (in main method)?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Solution 
{
    public List<String> letterCombinations(String digits) 
    {
        String[] letters = {"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", 
        "tuv", "wxyz"};
        List<String> rec = new LinkedList<>();
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        letterCombinations(digits, 0, letters, string, rec);
        return rec;
    }

private void letterCombinations(String digits, int number, String[] letters, 
StringBuilder string, List<String> rec) 
{
    if (digits.length() == number) 
    {
        rec.add(string.toString());
        return;
    }
    String letter = letters[digits.charAt(number) - '2'];
    for (int i = 0; i < letter.length(); i++)
    {
        string.append(letter.charAt(i));
        letterCombinations(digits, number + 1, letters, string, rec);
        string.deleteCharAt(string.length() - 1);
    }


}

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my `main()` for the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution o = new Solution();
        List<String> list1 = o.letterCombinations("623");
        System.out.println(list1);
    }
```

giving this as output:

```
mad, mae, maf, mbd, mbe, mbf, mcd, mce, mcf, nad, nae, naf, nbd, nbe, nbf, ncd, nce, ncf, oad, oae, oaf, obd, obe, obf, ocd, oce, ocf
```

You could format the output as required.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You ca run the program by following code in main method

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Solution t=new Solution ();
    List<String> list=t.letterCombinations("623");

    for(String listitem:list){
        System.out.println(listitem);
    }
}
```

Replace `List<String> rec = new LinkedList<>();` with `List<String> rec = new LinkedList<String>();`

Explanation:: 
1>> Since letterCombinations() is called from letterCombinations(), it is obvious that we have to call letterCombinations() first.As class contain only two of these method, we have to call letterCombinations() from main for proper functionality.
2>> letterCombinations() is not static method, so we have to call it by using object of class Solution and passing required parameter to it.

Try this, i hope this could help you to run above program